# Creating a CSR for a TPM

Tags: c#, csr, tpm

I'm trying to generate a CSR for a TPM in order to send it to a CA.
I'm having some difficulties since the CSR needs to be signed with the private key which is stored inside the TPM and most of the CSR generation codes that i stumbled upon doesn't know how to use the TPM.

the solution i thought about is creating the CSR myself (using c#) and signing it with a regular TPM command but i cant seem to find how to build a CSR from scratch without using an outer source.

Any opinions or suggestions on the matter will be welcomed.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find the certreq command documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/dn296456(v%3dws.11)

You can use the "certreq -new" command with an associated inf file in which you define the certificate request's characteristics including the "ProviderName" attribute. For the private key of the certificate to be created by and securely held in the TPM, you can indicate

```
ProviderName = "Microsoft Platform Crypto Provider"
```

If the certificate is meant to be a device certificate associated with the computer account rather than an individual user, you can also indicate the following in the inf file:

```
MachineKeySet = true
```

Many of the other attributes can be used to define the allowed use cases for the certificate and characteristics concerning its lifetime and renewal.